# Track scroll in google universal analytics

Tags: scroll, google-analytics

I would like to know if "scroll" event can be added to the Google analytics universal code? i have the below

```
setTimeout("ga('send','event','engaged users','page visit 30 seconds or more')",30000);
```

I wanted to track visits over 30secs that the scrolls

Comment: setTimeout has nothing to do with scrolling. If you are using jQuery, there is a nice scroll tracking plugin here: http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.scroll` which is available in the jQuery API.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  ga('send','event', 'engaged users');
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: I don't think so, break it in what way? Of course you can still wrap your `setTimeout` around the `ga` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins/libraries out there that add scroll tracking, but if you want to do it yourself make sure you don't send too many events.

You shouldn't send an event to GA directly on the window.onscroll event - this is fired dozens of times a second. It will chew through your hit allowance and it won't provide any useful data.

Even a sampled scroll event isn't much better (where you set a timeout every few hundred milliseconds to check if the user has scrolled) - it still sends potentially hundreds of events user page view.

You should either set it to fire on certain scroll "thresholds" (e.g. 20%, 50%), or, the better way in my opinion is to store a variable with the maximum scroll depth and then use the document.onbeforeunload event to fire just one event at the end of the user's page view. This gives way more accurate data and doesn't send too many events.

onbeforeunload has some browser inconsistencies though (especially on mobile), so you'll want a fallback for that. There's a full tutorial here on creating a cross-browser scroll tracking plugin with tons of code examples here: [building a better scroll tracking plugin](https://serps.com/blog/building-a-better-scroll-depth-tracking-plugin-google-analytics/)